# Variable name INSIDE quotation marks

Tags: php, string, variables

I was wondering if it is 100% correct to write variable names inside quotation marks.

I mean, is there any reason to do

```
echo "Hello my name is " . $name;
```

instead of

```
echo "Hello my name is $name";
```

Thanks.

Comment: I personally use the first way with single quotes - most because of my IDE then showing text and variables in different colors.

Comment: Sounds like a question out of boredom.

Comment: itachi: I'm beyond that stage of boredom.  Instead, I answer questions like these :)

Comment: echo "Hello my name is " . $name; , this way is kinda easy to read for me

Comment: Yes it is **100% correct PHP syntax** to write that way. PHP won't give you a syntax error. But you would have known that by executing your code and if uncertain, looking up the language in the manual. So -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, as I already commented, it is 100% correct PHP syntax to write that way. PHP won't give you a syntax error. But you would have known that by executing your code and if uncertain, looking up the language in the manual.

So the short answer is: Yes, 100% correct.

Then you asked *"is there any reason to do"* - and I'd like to highly suggest that you define the reason, because objectively, there ain't one. The "metrics" given in the accepted answer are misleading, because the problem has (and actually technically never can be strictly) not been isolated enough (even it could be) which leads to comparing wrong numbers.

If the difference between the two would be calculated, there literally is no difference that can be metriced - zero, nada, nothing.

Additionally, it even varies, sometimes even the one is faster, sometimes the other (if you run it, for code/demo see below):

```
10 runs à 100 000 iterations:

  single |  double  |   diff    |   real   
---------+----------+-----------+----------
0.014578 | 0.016206 | -0.001628 | -0.000000
0.015382 | 0.016352 | -0.000970 | -0.000000
0.015050 | 0.016156 | -0.001106 | -0.000000
0.015630 | 0.016280 | -0.000650 | -0.000000
0.015259 | 0.016220 | -0.000961 | -0.000000
0.015189 | 0.016190 | -0.001001 | -0.000000
0.014612 | 0.016264 | -0.001652 | -0.000000
0.015672 | 0.016257 | -0.000585 | -0.000000
0.015171 | 0.016251 | -0.001080 | -0.000000
0.014855 | 0.016166 | -0.001311 | -0.000000
```

Your "code" will get more improvement if you upgrade your PHP version constantly than wondering about which one is faster.

Rule of Thumb: Unless you don't run into a bottleneck, don't, never-ever "optimize" out of the blue. You will make your code more bad than good.

You give the reason why to write this or that way, because you need to read your code.

[image]

http://codepad.viper-7.com/z5p2xf

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530798/variable-name-inside-quotation-marks
 */
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$iterations = 100000;
$runs = 10;
printf("%d runs à %s iterations:\n\n", $runs, number_format($iterations, 0, '', ' '));

$plateaux = 0;
for ($r = 0; $r < $runs; $r++) {
    $time = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        ;
    }
    $plateaux += microtime(true) - $time;
}
$plateaux = $plateaux / $runs;


$results = array();

for ($r = 0; $r < $runs; $r++) {
    $result = &$results[];
    $time = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        "name$i";
    }
    $result[1] = microtime(true) - $time;


    $time = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        "name" . $i;
    }
    $result[0] = microtime(true) - $time; #
    unset($result);
}

echo "  single |  double  |   diff    |   real   \n";
echo "---------+----------+-----------+----------\n";

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $delta1 = $result[0] - $plateaux;
    $delta2 = $result[1] - $plateaux;
    $diff = $delta1 - $delta2;
    printf("%f | %f | %f | %f\n", $delta1, $delta2, $diff, $diff / $iterations);
}
```

Comment: Downvoted due to the silly picture.

Comment: @psynnott: Wait, I'll place that guy under a tire^^

Answer (score 3):

Both are fine and it's user preference which you find more readable - personally I prefer the first method of concatenating the variable.

However, bear in mind that:

```
echo "Hello my name is $name";
```

is not the same as

```
echo 'Hello my name is $name';
```

The second will output literally:

```
Hello my name is $name
```

Something to keep in mind.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the single quote. One of the common mistakes new developers make.

Answer (score 0):

it is purely a preference, both are 100% correct. i prefer first method of concatenation though for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is performance, inserting variable name into quotation uses more processor.
Demonstration:

```
<?php
$name='name';
$time = microtime(true);
for ($i=1; $i<100000; $i++){
    $name = "name".$i;
    echo "Hello my name is " . $name;
}
echo '<br>*** duration:'.(microtime(true)-$time).' milliseconds ***<br>';
$time = microtime(true);
for ($i=1; $i<100000; $i++){
    $name = "name$i";
    echo "Hello my name is $name";
}
echo '<br>*** duration:'.(microtime(true)-$time).' milliseconds ***<br>';
?>
```

Running this script on a Intel core I3-2120 3.3Ghz returns:
*** duration:0.25428795814514 milliseconds** 
 **duration:2.8928861618042 milliseconds ***

The difference is not big deal, but just to show the concept.

Comment: Sure its 100000 loops but its still 10x difference, right?

Comment: Yes, but don't get it as loop, think about a huge framework, with thousands of lines of code.. Is good to learn **good manners**

Comment: Another thing, the format *"Hello my name is " . $name* helps take advantage of IDE highlighting feature.

Comment: and how fast is it if you do _two_ echoes, instead of a string concatenation?

Comment: The relevant issue is the quotation, not the echo, you cannot replace **$name = "name".$i** with 2 echos if $name is going to be inserted into a database for example. But you still can perform several tests to see the differences (you just need an Apache server with a PHP interpreter)

Comment: FWIW on my MacPro with PHP 5.3.8 the interpolated version is (surprisingly) fastest, albeit only by ~ 20%.

Comment: Your answer is misleading therefore I've placed the warning.

Comment: @hakre: If an answer is misleading, downvote it and use comments to inform. Don't vandalize the answer directly.

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, some truth in your comment. I [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10547221/367456) below that hopefully will make it clear why there so much truth in the art (not vandalism).

Comment: @skafandri: I have no clue how you can manage such a difference with only 100 000 iterations. Also you metric much more than asked about.

Comment: Look at nikic's article [Disproving the Single Quotes Performance Myth](http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html). There's the reason why it's unnecessary to optimize at that stage.

Comment: @Dan Lee: Absolutely, and thanks for dropping the link here, it's a very good article by nikic.